# Facebook Android SDK Missing Currency Parameter for auto-logged events

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-analytics

I have implemented the Facebook SDK for android as stated by the Facebook Documentation and enabled auto logging for my events.

```
FacebookSdk.setAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled(true);
FacebookSdk.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(true);
FacebookSdk.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
```

I am using `com.facebook.android:facebook-core:16.1.3`
Automatic event tracking of installs and app activations is working, as well as my manually logged events.

##### However, in the diagnostics window of the event manager, I see the following warnings:

> Missing fb_mobile_add_to_cart Currency Parameter One or more of your
> fb_mobile_add_to_cart events is missing a currency parameter. This may
> affect your ability to see return on ad spend calculations.
>
> Missing fb_mobile_purchase Currency Parameter One or more of your
> fb_mobile_purchase events is missing a currency parameter. This may
> affect your ability to see return on ad spend calculations.
>
> Missing RecurringSubscriptionPayment Currency Parameter One or more of
> your RecurringSubscriptionPayment events is missing a currency
> parameter. This may affect your ability to see return on ad spend
> calculations.
>
> Missing fb_mobile_complete_registration Currency Parameter One or more
> of your fb_mobile_complete_registration events is missing a currency
> parameter. This may affect your ability to see return on ad spend
> calculations.
>
> Missing StartTrial Currency Parameter One or more of your StartTrial
> events is missing a currency parameter. This may affect your ability
> to see return on ad spend calculations.
>
> Missing Subscribe Currency Parameter One or more of your Subscribe
> events is missing a currency parameter. This may affect your ability
> to see return on ad spend calculations.

#### Screenshot example of warning

[image: Example of error]

Is there anything that I have missed to do to provide the currency for Facebook to correctly auto-log my android app's purchase events?